# Redux Toolkit addListener action does not register dynamic middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to add a dynamic listener middleware with RTK but it does not seem to intercept actions.I use the special `addListener` action which by the docs should allow inject dynamic middleware from a React component.On Redux dev tools I see `listenerMiddleware/add` action logged, but after that I see no actions intercepted by the middleware.

```
import { addListener} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = dispatch(
        addListener({
            predicate: () => {
                return true;
            },
            effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
                console.log('log', action);
                
            },
        })
    );
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, [])
}
```

Comment: Did you add the middleware instance to the `configureStore` setup?

Comment: @markerikson , no... it's not clear from the docs...but if I registered mw instance, so what's dynamic about this api?

Comment: @markerikson, can you elaborate and give an example how the api works?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the listener to your store - if you skip that step the middleware will also not listen to your store.

From the docs:

```js
// Create the middleware instance and methods
const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todos: todosReducer,
  },
  // Add the listener middleware to the store.
  // NOTE: Since this can receive actions with functions inside,
  // it should go before the serializability check middleware
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
})
```

Comment: So basically the mw is not added on run time just the listener config? That's what was inferred from the docs(mw lazy load or dynamic injection). thanks for answering!

Comment: As per the code example I just gave, you **have to add the middleware**: `getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware)`

Comment: You can then inject listeners into the middleware, but if you don't add the middleware into the store, it will not have any effect to the store.